# Understanding proof of Universal coefficient theorem for cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I am working through [Cohomology chapter on Hatcher's book](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch3.pdf) and I am having trouble with the proof of Universal Coefficient theorem for Cohomology. To be concrete I don't understand the last part of the proof of the Lema 3.1 (b). It is the highlighted  text on the picture below:

[image: cap]

My problems arise since I don't see why having the identity $\alpha \colon H \to H'$ can extend to maps between all the groups (modules) between the resolutions such that the induced maps are isomorphisms in cohomology. (I hope I have managed to explain my problem).

Thanks in advance.

Note:
I'm proving it for modules over PIDs but that shouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the fundamental lemma in homological algebra (see [here](http://www.indiana.edu/~jfdavis/teaching/m623/book.pdf) theorem $2.22$ page $36$ and the following corollary.)

If you take the identity the thesis of the theorem says in particular that you obtain a chain homotopy

Comment: First of all, thanks @Riccardo for the reference. I have read  very quickly through  it and I think it proves it in the same way I do (more or less), I mean: we prove there is a isomomorphism in cohomology but we do not prove it is the canonical isomorphism.

Comment: Well in the theorem it says that any two such maps are chain homotopic, so in cohomology they are the same map. I mean, canonical for me means that there are no choice to do (well, any choice gives the same result). That's exactly what the statement says right? Maybe I'm just overlooking something obvious here, but you lift the identity and *any lift* of it will gives you the same result in cohomology.

Comment: I explained myself badly, what I meant was that in the statement says that the isomorphism is induced by the identity map:
$$\text{id}^* \colon H^{n}(F';G) \to  H^{n}(F;G)$$

but I just proved there is an isomorphism:

Comment: $$\alpha_n^* \colon H^{n}(F';G) \to  H^{n}(F;G)$$

which is not necessarily induced by the identity.

Comment: I mean, I think the result in Hatcher is stronger that the result that I have proved or that appears in the reference you provided. But probably I am misunderstanding something. Thanks for your time anyway!

Comment: I'll give it a read in a few hours if it is not a problem:)

Comment: You were absolutely right!! It was a problem of notation, now I understand it!! I was being stupid and I just think to look at it from a different perspective. Thanks again. Answered accepted by the way.